# Which comes first - creating the nginx site `.conf` file or running `certbot-auto certonly`?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ansible, certbot

I'm trying to automate the setup of certbot + nginx on a server using Ansible.

The first time it runs, there are no letsencrypt certificates (yet). However I create the nginx conf as follows, referencing SSL/cert directories that *will* be created by certbot

```
server {

  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name         example.co;

  # ...

  # SSL
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}

server {
  if ($host = example.co) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  listen 80;
  server_name example.co;
  return 404;
}
```

Then later in the ansible play I run `certbot-auto` with the `--nginx` plugin, but I receive an error

```
> /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto certonly --nginx -n --agree-tos --text -d example.co --email admin@example.co

Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/fullchain.pem"
```

It seems that certbot first checks the nginx conf before proceeding (which makes sense) but the conf fails validation since it refers to directories that don't exist. Also, the `--nginx` plugin (or at least some other plugin) are required so I can't leave it off.

So I'm in a sort of chicken-and-egg situation because -

1. I can't create the nginx conf before running certbot because certbot tries to validate the nginx conf, and it fails because it references directories that don't exist
2. I can't run certbot before creating the nginx conf because certbot uses the site's conf to requires new cerificates

The only option i can see is to

- create the nginx conf *without* the `#SSL` lines
- run certbot to get new certs
- update the nginx conf file to add in the `#SSL` lines

This feels messy, but not sure if there's another way?

What's the right order to run this in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The .conf file surely needs to be there before running certbot. Certbot will then itself write the path to the certificates into the file, so step 3 should not be necessary.

Comment: Gotcha - but that modifies the state of original file which has an impact on re-running plays via ansible. I suppose there's no other way than just to accept it?

Comment: Maybe trick it by putting dummy certificates in place before anything?